# django:Could not load image

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-templates

I'm trying to load images from my models using .

forms fields

```
image_id = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=False)
image = forms.FileField(label = 'Select a Profile Image')
```

utility

```
def get_user(self):
    users = User.objects.all()
    data ={'users':users}
    return data
```

views

```
template_name= '/profile.html'
def get(self,request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = self.get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
    data.update({'user_detail':self.get_user(request.user)})
    return self.render_to_response(data)
```

settings

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media').replace('\\', '/')
```

templates

```
<center>
<img src="{{user_detail.profile_image.image}}" height="150px" width="150px">
</center>
```

I'm not getting image on page.

Comment: Do it uploaded in your server ?

Comment: the image is saved in database but not load on page, in brower inceptor its shows the full path of image, but not load on page.

Comment: Your others static files are downloaded or not ?

Comment: Can you able to open image in new tab?

Comment: no other static file

Comment: yes the image is open in another tab

Comment: In the src attribute of your <img> tag, do you have the full path or relative ?

Comment: {{user_detail.profile_image.image}} shows the full path

Comment: Try it out with `{{MEDIA_URL}}user_detail.profile_image.image.name`

Comment: it shows the location c:/project/kb/media/KBUser/abtimage.jpg in another tab

Comment: May it is the type of file. Do you tried with ImageField instead FileField ?

Comment: Can you post the HTMl generate because it is wired. I'm curious to know answer.

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
  
</head>
<body>

<center>
<img src="{{user_detail.profile_image.image}}" height="150px" width="150px" >
</center>

Comment: Your variable has not interpreted ? Do you send user_detail variable to your template ?

Comment: yes my all details are showing on page

Answer (score 0):

Both media files (those uploaded by the user) and static files (images, css, js used by your website) should be server by a web server like Apache, Nginx, etc.

Django makes no magic here and it's your responsibility to correctly configure your web server to serve those files.

For instance, say you have configured Django like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static'
STATIC_ROOT = '/var/www/mywebsite/static'

MEDIA_URL = '/media'
MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/mywebsite/media'
```

You should have configured a web server to serve files from those *_ROOT directories at the urls identified by *_URL variables. In Apache you can use two directives like these:

```
Alias /media /var/www/mywebsite/media
Alias /static /var/www/mywebsite/static
```

Without a web server doing the work for media and static files there is no chance for a browser to have access to those files.

Also I'd suggest to use [ImageField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ImageField) instead of FileField if the file to upload is an image.

Then in template you can write something like this to have the complete url to the image:

```
<img src="{{user_detail.profile_image.image.url}}" height="150px" width="150px">
```